# Remove Validation for Last Name Field from all places

Tags: magento-2.1, frontend, admin-panel, customer-attribute, custom-field

I want to remove validation from lastname field from admin panel as well as frontend in magento 2.1.12.Please tell me solution.

Comment: what you have tried ?

Comment: i already remove required and data-validate:true from lastname field in  vendor/magento/module-customer/view/frontend/template/widget/name.phtml.And also change eav_attribute table  is_required column from 1 to 0.

Comment: check the js file, I think validation also need to remove from js

Comment: which js file??

Comment: i have updated the answer,can you try

Comment: If it will work then mark as solution.

Answer (score 1):

First Step:

> Go to the 'eav_attribute' table in magento database, Find for the
>   'lastname' in 'attribute_code' column and find 'is_required' column
>   and set the value to 0.

You need to change below file as well

> Magento\Customer\Model\ResourceModel\CustomerRepository.php

```
if (!\Zend_Validate::is(trim($customer->getLastname()), 'NotEmpty')) {
            $exception->addError(__(InputException::REQUIRED_FIELD, ['fieldName' => 'lastname']));
        }
```

> Magento\Customer\Model\Customer.php

```
if (!\Zend_Validate::is(trim($this->getLastname()), 'NotEmpty')) {
            $errors[] = __('Please enter a last name.');
        }
```

> you need to comment above file code.

It will work!!

Comment: !\Zend_Validate::is(trim($customer->getLastname()) search by this

Comment: i will find in Vendor\Magento\module-customer\Model\ResourceModel\CustomerRepository.php.But this code is not find in this file.

Comment: its there vendor/magento/module-customer/Model/ResourceModel

Comment: if (!\Zend_Validate::is(trim($customer->getLastname()), 'NotEmpty')) {
            $exception->addError(__(InputException::REQUIRED_FIELD, ['fieldName' => 'lastname']));
        }

Comment: haven't u got yet ?

Comment: No,i didn't got it.

Comment: https://www.awesomescreenshot.com/image/3394554/3787175d2fa968907b788e6101865577

Comment: validate method is missing in my file.

Comment: ummm  :/ maybe version problem

Comment: I am using magento 2.1.12.

Comment: You have any idea about magento 2.1.12.

Comment: mine magento version 2.0.0

Comment: If you having the files on your local system, then just search "REQUIRED_FIELD, ['fieldName' => 'lastname']" in entire magento directory

Comment: Search result 0.

Comment: something must be missing

Answer (score 0):

I have the solution here from my question:

[Solution from StackExchange](https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/348043/100035)

This solved my issue, hope this will solve your's too.