# Magento 2 : Remove Mandatory Validation for Customer Fields eg. firstname, lastname

Tags: magento2, admin-panel, eav-attributes

I want to **remove the mandatory validation** for customer fields eg. firstname, lastname (both for frontend and admin).

I tried using **UpgradeData** to change the value of **is_required** field to **0** in the **eav_attribute** table.

This changes the required condition in the customer logged in page as not required for firstname and lastname.

But in the admin panel while adding new customer, the **firstname** field goes **not required**, **whereas the lastname field remains required.**

What can I do to **remove the required field in the lastname in admin panel.**

[image: Admin Panel With lastname as required]

UpgradeData.php

```
class UpgradeData implements UpgradeDataInterface
{
    public function __construct(
        EavSetup $eavSetupFactory
    )
    {
        $this->eavSetupFactory = $eavSetupFactory;
    }

    public function upgrade(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context) {
        $setup->startSetup();
        if (version_compare($context->getVersion(), '1.0.1', '<')) {
            $this->eavSetupFactory->updateAttribute(1,5,'is_required',0,null);
            $this->eavSetupFactory->updateAttribute(2,23,'is_required',0,null);
        
            $this->eavSetupFactory->updateAttribute(1,7,'is_required',0,null);
        
            $this->eavSetupFactory->updateAttribute(2,25,'is_required',0,null);
         }
         $setup->endSetup();

}
```

FirstName is_required as 0 in db
[image: FirstName is_required as 0]

LastName is_required as 0 in db
[image: LastName is_required as 0]

Comment: share the code which you are try into UpgradeData

Comment: I have added the code for UpgradeData

Comment: Bhavin, that doesn't work and thats not a solution too.

Comment: Jason, below solution is for admin only,
are you try it??

Comment: Below solution is working for admin??

Comment: Yes it's working

Comment: Now, you need for frontend also??

Comment: Because the frontend and backend have different logic.

Comment: No Bhavin, I have already done that for front-end. While doing that for back-end only I got struck! Thanks a lot for your help ❤️

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to remove require entry for admin you have replace 1 to 0 in "eav_attribute" on particular "attribut_code"[image]

and after that, you have also to comment or remove

`<validation> <rule name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">true</rule> </validation>`

from: vendor\magento\module-customer\view\base\ui_component\customer_form.xml
(override customer_form.xml file in your module)
[image]